# How can I know whether a USCIS field office does same-day oath ceremony?

Tags: usa, citizenship, paperwork

Some USCIS field offices do same-day oath ceremony, i.e. offer naturalization applicants to join the oath ceremony on the same day as the interview, assuming they passed the interview. How can I know whether a USCIS field office does same-day oath ceremonies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

Not all offices have ceremonies every day, not all the ceremonies happen in the office location, not every ceremony has slots available even if it happens that day, and not always the officers can complete the paperwork quickly enough even if you "passed" the interview. The fact that this was offered to someone in the same field office as yours doesn't mean that it would be offered to you, and vice versa.